# initialize ts files with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning to use Qt Creator and how to translate a file with `tr()`, I was wondering where can I find a `console` or `terminal` to write the line `lupdate myproject.pro`?

Comment: @koan : i'm on mac, i'm not sure where to look at : the terminal in "User/etc." or in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `QtCreator` right click on your `pro` file and select **Open Terminal Here...**. This is the easiest way since the terminal will automatically `cd` at your project's folder

Comment: thanks! ok, then you just write lupdate name_of_the_project.pro ? i wrote it, but i've got : `-bash: lupdate: command not found`

Comment: thanks, yeah it is not "installed", i followed Lucas's instructions to locate lupdate, i've got this: `The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.` then they ask me to launch `sudo launchctl etc.` and then ask for my password... i don't have a password, and it seems strange to use a password for that. Is there any link to "download" this "lupdate"..?

Comment: `lupdate` will be in the same `bin` folder as your qmake. Go under Qt Creator preferences and look under the "Qt" section to get your path. You can then just enter the full path to run qmake, i.e. `/usr/bin/blah/blah/bin/lupdate`

Comment: @Dave : thanks Dave, i did not find the section in Qt Creator preferences, but i can check at `/Users/myProfile/myProject-build` etc. to find the makefile file etc. but i could not find lupdate. If i look for lupdate with spotlight, a window from the Terminal is launched, with some explanations about it. But it does not want to use it if i use the commande line `lupdate` . If by any chance you have any idea Thanks

Comment: You need the full path to lupdate. For example, on my machine, to run lupdate from the command line, I use `~/Developer/qt/474_orig/bin/lupdate` (I built Qt from source; your path with certainly be different.) The path can be found in `Qt Creator > Preferences > Qt4` The "qmake location" is the same as your lupdate location.

Comment: @Dave : Hello Dave, thanks a lot for your help, alright i followed your instructions and i found out what the path to `lupdate` is. Could you please tell me what should i do now? i right-clicked on the `.pro` file, dragged the lupdate file onto the `Terminal` (the path appeared), and wrote `lupdate name-of-my-project.pro`, but it does not find `lupdate`, i think i'm doing it wrong, could you help me a bit with it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any other way to explain it that is not already written in the comments above. Upgrade to the latest Qt Creator and run it from the menu option as explained in my answer. That eliminates all the unknowns.

Comment: @Dave : thanks Dave for your help, sorry for the long conversation it was, i found out that i can use "Tools" in the menu that helped me a lot, thanks for your help, Cheers

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Qt Creator, you can just go to `Tools > External > Linguist > Update Translations (lrelease)`

Answer (score 3):

Click on a dir of your project in Qt Creator and select Open Terminal Here... There write:

```
lupdate -pro yourprofile.pro -ts translationxml.ts
```

after hat you'll want to create the file for the release:

```
lrelease translationxml.ts [-qm qmfile.qm]
```

and the file is produced. It is likely that lupdate and lrelease are not in the path. In that case use:

```
locate lupdate
```

to determine the complete path and use that. In my version it is in /QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin. To locate the lupdate binary you can also use spotlight.

Comment: thanks Luca for this great explanation, from the terminal i've got `The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.`, and then they ask for my password, after i wrote a new command line with `sudo`, but i don't have a password, i installed my Mac without any password. Do you know how i could "download" this thing i'm missing? thanks again

Comment: I suppose that error means the lacate database has never been created. You can try to use sudo updatedb. Not knowing the root password is somehow a more sever problem :-) try with no password. You can anyway also use spotlight to find lupdate.

Comment: thanks Luca, with spotlight, i found a `lupdate` program, i clicked on it and the `Terminal` showed me some infos about it. But if i try to use it, same thing as above, i tried with no password, it says "sorry, try again" and i had to switch on my mac again to have no more the "login" window from the Terminal! :) any other idea i could try? thanks anyway

Comment: I'm not understanding. Please, paste here the output of the command I posted above.

Comment: Hello Luca, thanks a lot for your help, here's what i did : right-clicked on the `.pro`file, entered "sudo updatedb" and then they asked for my password. i don't have one, and if i click on enter, it says "sorry, try again". i found the path to the `lupdate` file in QtSDK>Desktop>etc..../gcc/bin, do you know how i could use it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly as I posted in my answer. But replace lupdate with its absolute path instead.

Comment: thanks a lot Luca, sorry for those easy questions, okay it works for the first part, Qt Linguist is reading properly my tr variables, (i found out lupdate and release in `Tools`, from the Qt menu), but the release does not work, i have validated my translations, i then came back on Qt Creator, went to Tools>Linguist>release and i added `QTranslator translator; translator.load("myFile_en"); app.installTranslator(&translator);` to `main.cpp` , but the `qPushButton` still has the text from before. Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: This is not a chat. Please post another answer when you have another answer.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help, sorry for the long conversation it was. Cheers